# laravel - routes with same url and with diffrent middlewares and diffrents controllers override each others

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

so i have my routes defined within a global route group and inside i have two others groups, on with middleware 'employee' and one with middleware 'admin' and each one have their own controllers.

The two groups have a route index with the same url " /document " but each executes a different controller.

My problem is the index route that the last defined group always overrides the previous one.

The wanted behaviour is that if employee middleware is valid, execute the empController@index action, else if the admin controller is valid, execute the adminController@index action while keeping the same url for both, and i must keep each route in a seperate group, and the two routes must have the same url.

How can i acheive that? Thanks

here are the two conflicting routes

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => ['admin']], function() { Route::get('/document', 'Admin\DocumentController@index')->name('document.index'); .... });
Route::group(['middleware' => ['employee']], function() { Route::get('/document', 'DocumentController@index')->name('document.index'); .... });
```

Comment: can you paste you routes?

Comment: routes are based on URI and HTTP method ... you registered 2 routes with the same URI and method, it can only dispatch to 1 of them ... what do you expect it to do?

Comment: You can handle the redirect to X controller from the middleware

Comment: @Rooneyl you can not ... the 2 routes have the same URI, you will just keep redirecting back to itself

Comment: yeah the last defined route always overrides the old one(both have url /document). wanted behaviour is explained in the question

Comment: Routes are defined prior to any middlewares being run.  It would be incredibly inefficient to have the reverse as you'd have to evaluate all possible rules prior to determining the route.

Comment: i didn't even know that was possible, i think it would solve my problem, any idea on how to do it ? determin what route to define based on what middleware passes

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I was saying that would be incredibly inefficient..

Comment: inefficient means slow not impossible, right ?

Comment: I think you should research the request lifecycle..  The route determines the middleware, not the other way around.  Nothing is impossible but don't expect a good solution.

Comment: i know it is weird that i want to do it this way but i'm obliged to do it the other way around, a middleware defines which route is defined. can i please have a solution even if it is not good as you say, i spent the whole day searching with no solution found

Comment: Because noone has written a solution, it goes against the request lifecycle.  I'm not sure what you expect here, write your own routing solution

Comment: isn't there a solution to change route definition based on what middleware passes ?

Comment: no because like I said earlier, the route is defined before the middleware run in the request lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to perform different actions based on whether the request is coming from an employee or an admin. My suggestion would be to have one url, one route and one controller function for this.

Within the controller function (or in middleware that attaches its findings to the request if you wanted to do that), have logic to call one method or another.

A pseudo example in `PersonController.php`:

```
if(\Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
    // return an admin view or perform an admin function
else {
    // return an employee view or perform an employee function
}
```

Where the `isAdmin()` function is something you've defined in a model like `User.php`.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid, there must be diffrent controllers and diffrent routes

Comment: Then I'm missing where the issue lies. If there are different URLs hitting different routes then there shouldn't be an issue with what you have proposed. My guess would be that you are using parameters or wildcards in your route definitions that means one route is picking up requests that it shouldn't. I think posting the two routes in your routes file might help?

Comment: i think you should reread the question, i posted the two conflicting routes

Comment: Thanks, I can see them now. Your URIs for each route are identical. The Laravel way of defining routes means you have one route definition per URI. If there are more than one then the last one will be executed. The URIs need to differ somehow. Could you define a URI prefix like `admin/` for one of the route groups?

Comment: won't be posting the question if i was able to do that, it's doable but i cannot do it, i need something else